# Web URL connection Issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, domain-name

when I type

> www.arqade.com

into the address bar it states connection issues and doesn't display... I used to be able to access the site via this URL but it changed quite recently possibly 3 weeks or so ago. has there been changes to the sites URL? if not what could be causing that whether it be on my end or SE's end?